# Exact user defined expressions in Sympy derivatives

Tags: python, expression, sympy, user-defined

I am using Sympy to calculate the derivative of a complicated potential.
I have defined x, y, D0, e, C, k, d, b as Sympy Symbols.
Then I go on to do the following definitions:

```
import sympy as sm
x, y, D0, e, C, k, d, b = sm.symbols("x, y, D0, e, C, k, d, b")
phi = sm.atan2(y,x)
D = D0 + e*D0*sm.sin(k*phi)
rho = sm.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)

U = (2**b)/((2*D-d)**b)*(D - rho)**b
```

The symbol "U" stands for the 2D potential.

Now when I differentiate this vs. x using:

```
sm.simplify(U.diff(x))
```

I get an extremely long answer:
[image: extremely long naswer]

As you can see, in the answer there is explicitly the full expression for e.g. `D` :  `D0 + e*D0*sin(k*phi)` . Also, instead of sin(phi) I get sin(atan2(x,y) and the same happens for all of my defined expressions.

Is there a way for the result to automatically show my definitions instead of the long versions, without having the need to use the `subs` method for every single user-defined variable?

E.g. instead of `D0 + e*D0*sin(k*phi)` Sympy automatically uses the symbol `D`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `phi = sm.atan2(y,x)`, this assigns a Python variable to the result of `atan2(y, x)`. If you want `phi` to be a symbol, you have to define it that way

```
phi = symbols('phi')
```

and then substitute `phi` in as `atan2(y, x)` later.

```
U.subs(phi, atan2(y, x))
```

[This](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/gotchas.html) is worth reading regarding this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however it does not help me. As I stated in my question I am (was) looking for a way to do this without having to use the `subs` method for each variable. 

Furthermore, I still need the 'python variable' phi to actually write the potential, otherwise it gets way to complicated. So if I were to follow your answer, I would have to add 6 more commands to the existing code to redefine the references and do the substitutions.

I have also read 'this" before I even started to use sympy, as part of my study. It does not give any information for what I want to do.

Comment: What I want to do is to have PRE-defined expressions that are automatically included in the results of the sympy calculations without the need of `subs`. I use many different potentials.

Comment: @GeorgeDatseris SymPy requires you to be explicit about when you want to replace symbols with expressions in your calculations. I recommend building up a list of `(symbol, expr)` pairs for your calculation and using `subs` to replace them to the full expression at whatever point in your calculation you wish to replace them. You can do the whole thing using a single subs call if you pass a list of replacements to `subs`.

Comment: Yes, thank you. This seems the most efficient way. As I understand now, there is not any option that does not include an extra use of subs. So thank you for both of your answers.